# CustomList class, what is a good way to remove at a specified index?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, indexof

I have created a CustomList class with some methods such as Add(), Set(), and RemoveAt(). This CustomList class is meant to mimic the behavior of the List<> class without actually using it. 
When debugging my program I noticed that when I input the index of the string I want removed, my code successfully removes that string. But when I call the print method, it double prints the last string in the array. I'm assuming the error is within RemoveAt() and not Print() because Print() works perfectly fine when RemoveAt() is not called. I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

```
class CustomList
{
    private int count;
    private String[] data;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { value = count; }
    }
    public CustomList(int arrayNum)
    {
        data = new String[arrayNum];
    }
    public CustomList(): this(4)
    {
    }

    public void Add (String item)
    {
        if (count > data.Length)
        {
            String[] temp = new String[count * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = data[i];
            }
            data = temp;
        }
        data[count] = item;
        count++;
    }

    public int IndexOf (String item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].Contains(item))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public bool Contains (String item)
    {
        if (IndexOf(item) == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < count && index >= 0)
        {
            Array.Copy(data, index + 1, data, index, Count - (index + 1));
            count--;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(String item)
    {
        if (data.Contains(item))
        {
            int index = Array.IndexOf(data, item);
            RemoveAt(index);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

I'm a little confused with what you're saying, @germi. When I set the size to 4 and enter 4 strings, it successfully prints the 4 items in the array:
[image]

Comment: To *mimic* simply implement proper interface (see [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx));

Comment: Your `Print` is *not* working fine. Try adding four items to a `CustomList` (without setting the capacity in the ctor) and then printing it.

Comment: @germi The user is always prompted to enter the size of the list. I'm a little confused by what you're suggesting.

Comment: @corinne Did you see my answer? I think I can see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: @GaryMcGill yes, I saw your answer. Just to be clear, you were suggesting that I simply change <= to < and not that I change count to count-1, right? Because changing count to count-1 would always cut off the last element of the array.

Comment: @corinne Try the following code somewhere: `var c = new CustomList(); c.Add("a"); c.Add("b"); c.Add("c"); c.Add("d"); c.Print();` You'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because of what Gary McGill said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print loop should go from 0 to `count-1`, not from 0 to `count`. If you have 3 items (`count == 3`) then the indexes of those items are 0, 1, 2.

You're only getting away with accessing one too many items because of the way you're implementing `Remove`, which doesn't shrink the array (and so there still is a now-unused element at that index).

Change the `<=` into a `<`.

**Also, the `RemoveAt` method should do `count--`, not `Count--`.**

Comment: I made the suggested change but seem to still be having trouble with RemoveAt(). I updated my post with an image of the console. When I print after calling RemoveAt(int index) where index = 1, "pasta" is removed from the list, but the list then prints out as pizza, bread, fries, fries.

Comment: @corinne: yes, if you change it to `<` (as I see you have done), then that's enough.

Comment: OK, I see there's another problem: your `RemoveAt` method does `Count--` whereas I think you mean `count--`. In other words, you're not changing the `count` member.

Comment: I thought that because the Count property has a "set", Count-- would act the same as count--. I guess I should learn up more on properties. Anyway, changing it to count-- worked. RemoveAt()  now successfully removes the item at the entered index. Thanks

Comment: @corinne The `--` operator, when applied to a property value like that, will decrement the local copy of the value returned by the property (which is then promptly discarded). If you wanted to do it via the property you'd need to make an explicit assignment, such as `Count = Count - 1`.